# Are there any spells in Ars Magica that allow the creation of structures that are bigger on the inside?

Tags: ars-magica-5, artifacts

While I highly doubt that this will come up in the game I am in due to the fact that we are playing low level magus I was kind of curious as to whether there are spells that allow a building to be twenty square meters on the outside but fifty square meters on the inside. I am aware that this is a rather common fantasy trope but I couldn't find a mention of any such spells within the books.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Ars Magica concept I believe comes closest is the

## Regio

They are basically transitional layers of reality between Earth and one of the other planes (e.g. the Divine, the Infernal, the Faerie realm or the Magic realm). The inner layers of a Regio are quite commonly larger than the external (on-Earth) layer, so (for instance) walking around a Hawthorn tree (on Earth) could lead you into an entire Faerie forest (Regio level 1).

One specific example from the books is the Covenant of Crun Clach, from the book *Lion of the North*, page 74:

> Crun Clach is inside a sithean (shee-hen, faerie mound), which Caitlin Suil Uaine won in a shinty match in 954. [...]
>
> The hill of the covenant is a gently rounded slope with a “crown” of stones jutting out of the ground about ten feet below the top of the hill. [...]
>
> Once past the door, the characters are in the lowest level of the regio that the covenant occupies. Here are the stables, kitchens, and quarters of the mortal servants. [...]
>
> The second level of the regio can be entered by any of the sith. They appear to walk down corridors that have no exits, or open doors that did not exist before their arrival and do not exist once they pass. [...] Here are quarters for the bulk of the court, as well as a number of storerooms for vis and goods.
>
> The last level of the regio [...] is restricted to the magi, and here can be found their labs and living quarters. This level of the covenant is constructed of an intelligent, living stone that is named Am Balla (am ba-la, The Wall).

> #### Am Balla
>
> Am Balla actually exists in the lower levels, but normally does  not manifest there.
>
> There are no doors in the top level of the regio; rather, you ask Am Balla if it would please make an opening so you can enter your lab. [...]
>
> Am Balla has a fondness for Volya, Radislav’s familiar. He allows [the Faerie dog] to roam through [the Covenant as] he wants ([the Covenant leader] does not know this).

As showcased by Am Balla, there tend to be...uncontrollable elements involved, when Regios are created and maintained. Not too dissimilar from the Doctor's TARDIS, [which doesn't always function as the Doctor intended](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/The_Doctor%27s_TARDIS#Personality).

### Realms of Power

Chapter two of *Realms of Power: Magic* discusses some ways of interacting with/strengthening magical Auras in ways that could produce a Regio. In particular, check out the spell *Stratifying the Subtle Realities*, on page 14, which could give you about 15% yearly odds of generating a Regio from an Aura.

## Bottomless Bag

(Credit to Arkhaic)

In Magi of Hermes, p. 126, there is an example of a bag with an enchantment which explicitly "makes the space inside it far bigger than it should be".

Note that this is crafted by Scipio, a Merinita (Faerie) Magus with Strong Faerie Blood and a Major Magical Focus for Faerie Glamours at some point between 60 and 75 years past his Gauntlet, so we are talking about a quite old specialist - definitely not something a younger and less specialized Maga could create, but possibly something Scipio could gift to a valued apprentice.

> ### Bag without Bottom
>
> MuIm 30
>
> Pen +9, +2/day, constant effect
>
> R: Personal D: Sun T: Room
>
> The Glamour enchantment (see page 101 in *Houses of Hermes: Mystery Cults*) inside this bag makes the space inside it far bigger than it should be. [...]
>
> (Base 10, +2 Sun, +2 Room; +1 2/day, +3 environmental trigger for total of 34 levels)

Comment: In addition to these, Magi of Hermes pg. 126 has a glamour enchantment for a "Bottomless Bag" that is bigger on the inside.

Comment: @Arkhaic Added it, thanks for the pointer! I must confess to not having read the books on sample Magi particularly thoroughly. Interestingly, like Am Balla, the Bag is strongly associated with Faerie and not Magic.